# jquery event target not focusing new targets

Tags: jquery

I am trying to navigate a form using keyboard tab.

```
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.which != 9) {
        }else{
            if($(e.target).hasClass('pro')){
                $('#np').hide();
            }else{
                $('#np').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The strange thing here is the e.target is not triggered at the input where the cursor is blinking but at the previous input, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the event to `keyup` instead of `keydown`. `keydown` will trigger at the previous input field, and by the time `keyup` is triggered, the focus is already available to the new input field. In below code, `console.log` will print the new input element.

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target))
    if (e.which != 9) {
    } else {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('pro')) {
            $('#np').hide();
        } else {
            $('#np').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) event

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 9) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('pro')) {
            $('#np').hide();
        } else {
            $('#np').show();
        }
    }
});
```